# Virtualbox not passing internet to guest OS

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtualbox

I am trying to run a Linux virtual machine inside Virtualbox, host OS is Windows 10. I have the latest version of Virtualbox and I have installed it and set it up according to the online manual [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/). I have installed the guest OS and it runs fine; however, it seems that internet access is not being passed to the guest OS. I am trying to use NAT networking mode, which apparently should just work 'out of the box', but it's not. I have tried two different virtual machines with both Lubuntu and Trisquel Linux as guest OSes, but neither is receiving internet.

How/where should I start to troubleshoot what might be causing the problem?

The output of `ip link show` on the Lubuntu guest is given below. From this, it seems that it is finding the virtual network adapter.

[image: output of 'ip link show']

Output of `ip route` on VM:

[image: output of 'ip route']

Comment: Try bridged networking, and if this works try switching back to NAT.

Comment: @harrymc thanks for the suggestion. However, I would rather not use bridged networking, as the host is my company PC connected to the office network. They don't like 'non-approved' devices being connected to the company network, so I specifically want to use NAT, to access internet via the host machine's connection.

Comment: This test takes about one minute, but I wouldn't want to put you in an uncomfortable situation.

Comment: @harrymc I'll try it a bit later on my home network. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: What says `ip route` in the VM? What kind of "internet" do you expect? HTTP/HTTPS only or other protocols (SSH, SMTP, IMAP...). Is you company using a proxy?

Comment: @xenoid I have added the output of 'ip route' on the VM to my question. In terms of 'what internet?', just HTTP/HTTPS would be fine. My company does use a proxy; however, I had assumed that the Virtualbox host would go through that, in the same way as any other application.

Comment: Avoid pasting screenshot images, paste the plain text. Your route looks normal. Can you ping other hosts inside your company from the VM?  But keep in mind that things inside the VM won't see the proxy settings of the host, you have to find them (not always easy) in Windows and add them in the VM, and pray that the proxy isn't too picky about "user agents".

Comment: @xenoid it's tricky for me to paste the output text, because of the connectivity issues I am having with the VM. I tried pinging the network gateway of my host machine from the VM and that worked, so perhaps the issue is with the proxy. As I mentioned to harrymc, I will try it on my home network later and see if that makes a difference. I have no idea about the 'user agent' thing, but I can see that might also be a possible issue. Might be best to pass this by my company IT dept, to make sure this is all ok.

Comment: If you have the VBox extensions installed, the clipboard is common between VM and host.

Comment: @xenoid the internet is working fine in the VM on my home network, so I think you were right - it must be the proxy on my work network that is causing it. I'll try to configure the proxy on the VM tomorrow and see if that solves it. Thanks!